# How to create a dialog with browse button using job in Axapta X++?

Tags: axapta, x++

How to create a dialog with browse button(to browse a file) using job in Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2009 with X++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use extended data type FilenameOpen or FilenameSave for the dialog field.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
info(WinAPI::getOpenFileName(0, ['TEXT FILE', '*' + '.TXT'], @'C:\', 'Select a file'));
```